# What are the use cases for zero-dimensions array in common lisp

Tags: arrays, common-lisp

[CLTL](https://faculty.cc.gatech.edu/%7Eisbell/references/lisp/clm/node157.html) says the following: "In principle, an array in Common Lisp may have any number of dimensions, including zero. (A zero-dimensional array has exactly one element.)"

I'm talking about something like `(make-array nil :initial-element 1)`

As far as i can see, these zero-dims arrays even have their own read syntax, like `#0A1`, but they're not even considered to be sequences, so i can't coerce/concat/traverse them. The only thing i found out you can do, is to get/set its singleton element. So what's the purpose for having this not-exactly-an-array array kind? Why not just use arrays of length 1 (or just the value without any wrapper)?

Comment: _Why_ questions are so opinionated and hard to answer.  _Uniformity_ is almost certainly the justification that the creators had in mind.  But it may be impossible to make _you_ personally satisfied with someone else's justification, especially when phrased as "why not just use (some valid alternative)" -- that's a loaded question.  You're right: you **can** use arrays of length 1.  But some day you may find a piece of code that is easier to read if that one special case goes away by making it use a zero-dimensional array.  Reducing cognitive load when reading code is a valid motivation.

Answer (score 3):

*"So what's the purpose for having this not-exactly-an-array array kind?"* This may miss the point: a zero-dimensional array *is* an array type, and a naked value such as `1` is not an array type. *"What are the use cases"* may be too broad, but anytime you need an array type that can hold exactly one value a zero-dimensional array may be a good choice.

This idea has precedence in mathematics: tensors can be represented as multi-dimensional arrays where zero-dimensional arrays represent scalars, one-dimensional arrays represent vectors, two-dimensional arrays represent matrices, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, the tensors pov is convincing ). Maybe the `use cases` phrasing is a bit incorrect. I rather mean 'how do you, as a lisper, use this feature)?'

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can also have 0 in the dimension list:

```
(make-array (list 0 10) :initial-element 3)
=> #2A()
```

This allows code that manipulates matrices in a generic way to avoid handling corner cases when one dimension is zero, I don't know of such cases myself but for example this question about Mathematica https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39522/zero-dimensional-matrices is talking about difficulties handling such corner cases.

I think its helpful in terms of robustness and uniformity if there is no constraint for arrays to be limited to non-zero dimensions, and that is probably why it is allowed.

By itself a zero-dimensional array can be useful to implement a boxed-value, but you are right that there are other ways to implement that: a vector of size 1, a simple struct `(defstruct box thing)`, etc. so another way to look at it is to find out which implementation costs less in terms of memory or access time, and maybe zero-dimensional arrays can be implemented more efficiently than arrays of size 1.

For example, using SBCL, `(aref b)` does not need to check for the validity of the index in the array, whereas `(aref b 0)` performs a check.

```
(defun zero (b)                                                                                                                                                                              
   (declare (optimize (safety 1) (speed 3) (space 3) (debug 3)))                                                                                                                             
   (declare (type (simple-array t nil) b))                                                                                                                                                   
   (aref b))
```

```
; disassembly for ZERO                                                                                                                                                                            
; Size: 24 bytes. Origin: #x54B8F453                          ; ZERO                                                                                                                              
; 53:       498B4510         MOV RAX, [R13+16]                ; thread.binding-stack-pointer                                                                                                      
; 57:       488945F8         MOV [RBP-8], RAX                                                                                                                                                     
; 5B:       488B4209         MOV RAX, [RDX+9]                                                                                                                                                     
; 5F:       488B5001         MOV RDX, [RAX+1]                                                                                                                                                     
; 63:       488BE5           MOV RSP, RBP                                                                                                                                                         
; 66:       F8               CLC                                                                                                                                                                  
; 67:       5D               POP RBP                                                                                                                                                              
; 68:       C3               RET                                                                                                                                                                  
; 69:       CC10             INT3 16                          ; Invalid argument count trap
```

```
(defun one (b)                                                                                                                                                                              
   (declare (optimize (safety 1) (speed 3) (space 3) (debug 3)))                                                                                                                             
   (declare (type (simple-array t 1) b))                                                                                                                                                     
   (aref b 0))
```

```
; disassembly for ONE                                                                                                                                                                             
; Size: 34 bytes. Origin: #x54B009BD                          ; ONE                                                                                                                               
; BD:       498B4510         MOV RAX, [R13+16]                ; thread.binding-stack-pointer                                                                                                      
; C1:       488945F8         MOV [RBP-8], RAX                                                                                                                                                     
; C5:       48837AF900       CMP QWORD PTR [RDX-7], 0                                                                                                                                             
; CA:       760C             JBE L0                                                                                                                                                               
; CC:       488B5201         MOV RDX, [RDX+1]                                                                                                                                                     
; D0:       488BE5           MOV RSP, RBP                                                                                                                                                         
; D3:       F8               CLC                                                                                                                                                                  
; D4:       5D               POP RBP                                                                                                                                                              
; D5:       C3               RET                                                                                                                                                                  
; D6:       CC10             INT3 16                          ; Invalid argument count trap                                                                                                       
; D8: L0:   CC24             INT3 36                          ; INVALID-VECTOR-INDEX-ERROR                                                                                                        
; DA:       08               BYTE #X08                        ; RDX(d)                                                                                                                            
; DB:       82808010         BYTE #X82, #X80, #X80, #X10      ; 0
```

This is not definitive as this corner case could be improved over time, but in a way the zero-dimensional array expresses more clearly the constraint here.

Comment: thanks! this 'better performance' take is rather interesting. `Note that you can also have 0 in the dimension list`, this one is what i easily understand.. the array with zero length in some axis, totally fits the general array idea. `nil` axis in contrast seems to be inconsistent. Well the `tensor` idea from the other answer generalizes it to be the sane idea for me ). Still, if you maybe know where can i read on  the reason for this design, i'd really appreciate!

Comment: @leetwinski I'm sorry but I don't have any reference to point you at that would explain the decision behind this, maybe someone else will be able to, but searching around comp.lang.lisp doesn't give a lot of results (and probably the discussion was made elsewhere).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the question of consistency, a zero-dimensional array is a *box*: it is a mutable object which holds a reference to exactly one other object.

Boxes are a useful enough notion that other languages have explicit types for them: for instance Racket has [boxes](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/boxes.html).

In addition, a zero dimensional array can of course constrain the type of its element in the way that any array can, depending on what specialised array types exist in the implementation.

Some implementations also have weak arrays, a zero-dimensional weak array is therefore a weak box, whose contents may be garbage-collected.

Answer (score -1):

More than likely so you can have a 'vector' only DSL, like R does.  In R *everything*, even single numbers, is an array/vector.